# Php Function Help Needed

Tags: php, function

So I modify the code a bit but its seems like the `rand()` function isn't working properly why ? Below is my code for that also my whole code link is given below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan=2 align=right>
    <font color=red>*</font>Order ID
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo rand();?>' disabled>
  </td>
</tr>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zw7-bxp

Comment: what do you want here?

Comment: <?php echo rand(2600,9900);?> this is what i get inside the text box

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: i want the function to generate me a rand number inside the text box , but it isn't generating  one for me

Comment: It works for me, it has a random number in the disabled textbox

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3bt-s6u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using smarty. Therefore please try using .

```
 {php}echo rand();{/php}
```

Comment: And why you think so he is using `smarty`?

Comment: There is no sign of smarty in there. If he were using a template engine, he wouldnt use a php function INSIDE the template because if he does that, he doesnt need a template engine ...

Comment: I checked php fiddle link. You should too ;)

Comment: Kay. Youre right. But it doesnt make sense to call a php-function inside the template. Thats what a template-engine should prevent.

Comment: gotca working , So smarty use {php} and {/php} ?why so and how?

Comment: In some rare occasions you might need to use php code inside smarty that is why they implemented {php} tag to that engine at first place please check http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl for more info ...

Comment: @YUNOWORK but it seems to be working fine? but how is it possible?i am confused

Comment: @Madcoe so for example , now i have to add this column inside the database too ? so can i edit the mysql function and just add it directly ? or do i need to have something else too ?

Comment: @Madcoe Why should this be necessary? Call the `rand()` inside the php file and give it to the template. Easy and no unnecessary code inside the template.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I didn't say it is necessary. I showed how to use php inside smarty. But correct way of doing a random in smarty using math library of smarty . here {math equation='rand(1,10)'}

Comment: @user3296356 Ideally you should try not to use any php inside your template files. That is why you are using a template engine. Using php codes will slow down your templates to load and won't give you any advantage of caching of temlates. Also it will make your codes more confusing.

Comment: @Madcoe could you tell me what does $reg_userinfo[7] means on this statement  <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{$reg_userinfo[7]|replace:'"':'&quot;'}"></td>

Comment: @user3296356  $reg_userinfo[7] is same as php it shows you have an array called $reg_userinfo and accessing 7th element in it. Definitions after | means you are calling a function defined inside smarties libraries in your case you are calling replace function to replace " with &quot; . You have to do that in your code otherwise your html will have a syntax error.

Comment: @Madcoe can you please help me for last ? i have put track id inside the query of insert but i got an error , Below the the query for the same

Comment: Please post another question on stack overflow therefore you will get faster responses and people won't be confused when they look at this post in the future.

Answer (score -1):

From the php-docs:

```
If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random
integer between 0 and getrandmax(). If you want a random number between 5 and 15
(inclusive), for example, use rand(5, 15).
```

So better use:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 align=right>
        <font color=red>*</font>Order ID
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo rand(min_value, max value);?>' disabled>
    </td>
</tr>
```